# Process monitoring script

Tags: logging, scheduled-tasks, sh, status-monitoring

I wrote a script which logs memory usage of a process (pid in file), and reacts in case a limit is reached. I run the script nightly. In my case, the process concerned propably has a memory leak and locks up the whole system after a couple of days. Hence, the script should reboot the system if excess memory is used. Logged memory usage values are formated to have 1 decimal place.

The code works, but I'd like to know if and how I could optimize it, and if there are no mistakes.

```
#!/bin/sh

# process_monitor.sh
#
# monitor specific process
# customized for memory usage monitor (can easily be changed)
# customized to perform system reboot if limit is exceeded (can easily be changed)
# by geohei <xxxx@xxxx.xx>
# created : 14.10.2016
# revised : n/a
#
# use cron to trigger (e.g. nightly at 04:15 '15 4 * * * ~/process_monitor.sh'
# /bin/bc is used (possibly not installed by default)
#
# $pidfile must include path
# $logpath is used to save 'process_monitor.log' file (omit trailing '/')
# $pidlimit can be floating point (e.g. 14.1)

pidfile='/tmp/process.pid'
logpath='~'
pidlimit=20.0

pidvalue=$(ps -p $(eval "cat $echo $pidfile") -o %mem --no-headers)

if [ "$(echo "${pidvalue} > ${pidlimit}" | bc)" -eq 1 ]; then
    # log $pidvalue, $pidlimit and reboot system
    echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')   pidvalue: $pidvalue, pidlimit: $(echo $pidlimit | awk '{printf "%.1f\n", int($1)}') - reboot" >> $logpath/process_monitor.log
    shutdown -r -t 10
    exit 1
else
    # log $pidvalue, $pidlimit
    echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')   pidvalue: $pidvalue, pidlimit: $pidlimit" >> $logpath/process_monitor.log
fi

exit 0
```

That's how the log looks like:

```
...
2016-10-14 04:15:04   pidvalue: 19.2, pidlimit: 20.0
2016-10-15 04:15:03   pidvalue: 20.4, pidlimit: 20.0 - reboot
...
```

Any remarks, comments or suggestions?

Comment: Rebooting the machine because one process allocated too much memory sounds like a drastic measure. Why wouldn't you just stop and restart the offending process?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. The script was designed to have the basic structure for all kind of things which might be triggered. Of course I will adapt the script on the real productive server to first restart the monitored process at a first stage. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3):

Don't write custom scripts for common sysadmin tasks. Using the proper tools will get the job done better, and the solution will be more maintainable — especially by any colleagues you might have.

Using [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#RESOURCE-TESTING), for example, this would just be a matter of writing a simple configuration file.

```
set logfile /root/process_monitor.log
check process myproc with pidfile /tmp/pidfile.pid
    restart program = "shutdown -r -t 10"  # draconian!
    every "15 4 * * *"
    if memory > 20 MB then restart myproc
```

Comment: Wow! I had no clue such a tool existed. Going to dig myself through the man pages. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Although @200_success already gave a great answer,
there are some glaring issues with the posted code that should be pointed so you can avoid them in the future.

---

`eval` is *evil*. Not really, but it's prone to abuses, and it's very hard to justify its use. This is a very twisted example:

> ```
> pidvalue=$(ps -p $(eval "cat $echo $pidfile") -o %mem --no-headers)
> ```

That should be simply:

```
pidvalue=$(ps -p $(cat "$pidfile") -o %mem --no-headers)
```

---

Using `bc` for a boolean evaluation is extremely awkward:

> ```
> if [ "$(echo "${pidvalue} > ${pidlimit}" | bc)" -eq 1 ]; then
> ```

Write like this:

```
if [ "${pidvalue}" -gt "${pidlimit}" ]; then
```

I used `-gt` because you are using `/bin/sh`. If you don't mind changing that to Bash, then it would become even more simple and natural:

```
if (( pidvalue > pidlimit )); then
```

---

These lines are very similar:

> ```
> echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')   pidvalue: $pidvalue, pidlimit: $(echo $pidlimit | awk '{printf "%.1f\n", int($1)}') - reboot" >> $logpath/process_monitor.log
> # ...
> echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')   pidvalue: $pidvalue, pidlimit: $pidlimit" >> $logpath/process_monitor.log
> ```

Probably you copy-pasted and customized.
That's a very bad habit.
Try to generalize instead.
Extract common values to variables,
such as the common prefix `$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')   pidvalue: $pidvalue, pidlimit:`.
Extract common operations to helper functions,
such as logging to `$logpath/process_monitor.log`.

---

The last command of the program is `exit 0`. That's strange, for several reasons:

- The script would exit anyway, you don't need to call `exit` explicitly.
- By default, the exit code is the status code of the last command. An exit code of 0 means success. By running `exit 0` as the last statement, you may cover up the failure of the last command. That's a suspicious thing to do.